# Java to Database Connection : Exception

Tags: java, database

I am connecting my java program to mysql database. But i get an exception block executed instead of getting connected i.e, "Connection Failed!!".

```
  import java.sql.*;
  public class Mysqltest 
 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String username ="root";
    String password ="bharath12";
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/";
    String dbName = "sample";
    String driver= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection con =null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, username, password);
        System.out.println("Connection successfully established.");
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Connection terminated !");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection failed !!");
    }
}
    }
```

What would be the error in the above code?
I deliberately changed mysql port to 3307 during installation (hence, localhost:3307)

Comment: You should use `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block, because there is a reason behind that method. It gives you exactly where you got exception.

Comment: Update stack-trace. e.printStackTrace() in catch block.

Comment: And possible cause of `exception` may be you don't have the jar file in your classpath. That is what all can be said from the above code.

Comment: @RohitJain possibly there could be other possibilities too. :)

Comment: @Quoi. May be. Can't say anything until I see the stacktrace

Comment: Yes. Now it shows a "java.lang.ClassNotFound Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: Add the `com.mysql.jdbc` jar file in your classpath.. It would be with the name: - `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`. With a different version though.

Comment: Here's my classpath i set in Environment Varialbles:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;.; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;"

Comment: Are you running the code from some IDE?

Comment: Maybe not use spaces in classpath. I don't rememeber for sure, but most of the time they mean trouble.

Comment: @RohitJain That doesn't eliminate `ClassNotFoundException`, though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik. May be or may be not. Because the `Jar` file is in the classpath. So, I think there is some wierd problem.

Comment: @RohitJain Definitely not. If that exception is to be thrown, it will be thrown before we get to `newInstance`. Otherwise what object do you think that method would be invoked on?

Comment: @RohitJain The same exception arises

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah! So there is the problem in classpath. the space before the last path is making the problem. Say it when I copied it to notepad.

Comment: Yes. Its done. The problem was in the class path. Only a single semi-colon was enough for separation of two paths(where i used ;.; instead). Anyways! Thank you friends!!

Comment: No, `;.;` is legal. This means that the current working directory is on the classpath. The problem is in the extra space, as explained in your accepted answer.

Comment: Yes. My Java code gets executed but i have the same problem when i try to connect Mysql and JSP. Tomcat shows a ClassNotFound Exception. The same exception mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have additional space only separator allowed is in classpath variable for windows is `;`
So your `CLASSPATH` variable should be like below-

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;
```

There is a space in your class path before `mysql` jar.

Moving ahead it is advisable to use class path with `-cp` option rather than global `CLASSPATH` since global class path has precedence over application class path it can create problems if there are same classe names in different jar which is mentioned in Global Classpath.

You can also start using editor like `Eclipse` in which you can simply add required `jar` files in build path.

Comment: Yes. Thats wat d problem was. Thank you.

Comment: Using a global `CLASSPATH` variable is strongly discouraged. You should proved the classpath using the `-cp` switch for the `java` command or setup the libraries properly in your IDE.